# Django OSError [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error:

```
OSError at /index/
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoTestS\\templates\\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x00000262E5F2F2B0>'
```

I believe this is due to my django code failing to find my template file. The code to get the template in django is as follows:

```
index_model = loader.get_template('index.html')
```

and my template dict is as follows:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
             'C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\DjangoTestS',],
```

Solutions from similar questions I have tried:

- Hard coded the project location into the templates dict. Originally it was a way that should generally find the templates folder of any project, but that did not work. The hard coded way did not work either.
- A pycharm shell helper change that hard coded a path element to the pycharm projects folder. Did not work either.

As requested, here is the view that is causing the error:
    def table_view(request):

```
ip_address = get_client_ip(request)
browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
cur_visit = models.visit()
cur_visit.ip_address = ip_address
cur_visit.browser = browser
cur_visit.save()

index_model = loader.get_template('index.html')

all_visitors = models.visit.objects.all()

context = {'all_visitors': all_visitors}
return render(request, index_model, context)


def get_client_ip(request):
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
return ip
```

Comment: could you write your view where you are trying to render template?

Comment: @Gahan def table_view(request):

    ip_address = get_client_ip(request)
    browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    cur_visit = models.visit()
    cur_visit.ip_address = ip_address
    cur_visit.browser = browser
    cur_visit.save()

    index_model = loader.get_template('index.html')

    all_visitors = models.visit.objects.all()

    context = {'all_visitors': all_visitors}
    return render(request, index_model, context)

Comment: Sorry about bad formatting, not understanding why it isn't formatting correctly.

Comment: what is content of DIRS in settings/TEMPLATES ?
I had the same problem and it happened because of my DIRS.

Answer (score 2):

if your template is stored in directory called `template_dir`, then you can modify your code as `'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template_dir')]`. In your code you have joined project directory path with `templates`. Which(directory) probably does not exist.

the `get_template` function returns a `Template` object, which does not fit the function template for `render`, it(`render`) takes the template name`template.html` directly.

Comment: Unfortunately my templates folder is actually called 'templates' so I do not think that is the issue here. Thanks for responding.

Comment: `render()` takes template name and not the template object( which is returned by the `get_template` , function. If you want o use `get_template` you can call `render` as a function of `Template` object, like so `HttpResponse(t.render(c, request), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')`[copied from the link] 
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

> OSError at /url_path/ 
>  [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

And that was simply because of the argument order while rendering. This one throws the error:

```
def contact(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'contact.html',
    return render(request, context, template)
```

This one is error-free:

```
def contact(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'contact.html',
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Try to maintain the order in your project.