# How to fix OSError (invalid argument) error in django

Tags: python, django

I get this error at django.

> OSError at /dog_list/
>   [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "C:\Users\Kanan\Desktop\blank\cv\templates\"

My views.py file is like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from dog.models import User, Dog
from django.http import Http404


# Create your views here.

def dog(request):
    context = {

        "dog_list": Dog.objects.all()
    }

    return render('dog.html', request, context=context)
```

And my html file is like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Welcome to Dog sharing platform</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Dog types </h2>
    <li>
        {% for dog in dog_list %}
        <ul>{{dog.dog_list}}</ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </li>


</body>
```

My models.py file is given below

```
    class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Dog(models.Model):
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.FloatField(default=0.5)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.breed
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question looks similar to:
[Django OSError [Errno 22] Invalid Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015104/django-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument)

I think you will need to re-order the arguments to render as follows:

```
return render(request, 'dog.html', context=context)
```

Good luck